# PopupMenu does not show when in DLL

Tags: dll, freepascal, lazarus

I am developing a plugin for the "PL/SQL Developer" IDE (from Allround Automations) in Lazarus 1.2.4/FreePascal 2.6.4. The plugin is an x86 DLL.

Everything has been working fine so far, except for one thing. Here's the setup:

- I have a `TForm` with a `TTreeView` and a `TPopupMenu` components on it.
- The `TPopupMenu` component is assigned to the `TTreeView.PopupMenu` property.
- The `TPopupMenu` component has nonzero number of menu items created and properties `AutoPopup := true`, `TrackButton := tbRightButton` set.

And here's the issue ...
When the form is shown at run-time and the tree view is right-clicked:

- The popup menu does not get visible.
- Yet, the popup menu's `OnPopup` event gets executed.

I tried doing this in the minimalistic way - a DLL that has just one export which spawns the form with a treeview and a popup menu, then running the proc. via the Win's `rundll32.exe`. The same result - no popup menu.

If I try the same setup (form+treeview+popupmenu) from a standalone Win application, it works OK - the popup menu shows up.

Any help on this?

May or may not be related to it:
The PL/SQL Developer's bundled "plugin demo 2 / Delphi" does an assigment of `Application.Handle := IDE_GetAppHandle;` (with the `IDE_GetAppHandle` being a callback function from the PLSQL Developer IDE) which I can't do in FPC, since the `TApplication` class does not have the `Handle` property.

Any help on this, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution on the FreePascal+Lazarus forum: http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,24135.msg144938.html#msg144938

Excerpt: It is a bug in the LCL. But since the LCL sources are distributed along with FPC+Lazarus, you can patch the LCL yourself:

- Edit the `${lazarus-install-folder}/lcl/interfaces/win32/win32obj`.
- Find the `TWin32WidgetSet.AppInit` procedure definition.
- Find the call to `CreateAppHandle` (commented as `// Create parent of all windows, 'button on taskbar'`) inside the procedure.
- Move the call to `CreateAppHandle` from inside the `if not IsLibrary then` upwards, immediately before the `if`.
- Save, compile, build ... done.

Apparently, it **was** related to the `Application.Handle` issue.

Comment: (minor detail that's LCL though, not FCL. FCL are units like custapp)

Comment: As an Oracle dev, I don't distinguish between different flavours of its component/unit libraries; it's all just a bunch of Pascal units to me, sorry. :-) Thank you for spotting.